# Different branches share a single index file?

Tags: git, git-branch, git-checkout

I am confused about the scenario below

```
git init  (command 0)
Initialized empty Git repository in a path;

echo line1 >a (command 1)
git add a  (command 2)`

git commit -m 'first commit' (command 3)
1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
create mode 100644 a

git branch b (command 4)
echo line2 >>a (command 5)

git checkout b  (command 6)
Switched to branch 'b'

git status (command 7)
Changes not staged for commit

git checkout master (command 8)
Switched to branch 'master'

git add a  (command 9)
git status (command 10)
Changes to be committed

git checkout b  (command 11)
Switched to branch 'b'

git status  (command 12)
Changes to be committed:
```

Q1: since branch b was created after commit, so the initial repository of b should contain file 'a', after switched to b, the working directory should be initialized with the last commit on branch b. but the file a in working directory didn't change(still contains 2 lines), is this some kind of mechanism to prevent lost changes?

Q2: after command 8, the current branch should be master, file 'a' then be added to the index and then checkout back to branch b, at that time, git status returns (Changes to be committed). but I added file 'a' in the master branch, why I can submit it on the other branch? 
And I am a little confused about how the index file change(or don't change) when checkout branches

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's not that the *branches* share an index file (although, in effect, they do). Rather, it's that there is *only the one index file* for the repository as a whole. More precisely, there's one distinguished index for each work-tree; and a repository has one work-tree (until you add more) so it has just the one index (until you add more work-trees). Any `git checkout branch` must use that one index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Realize: after you add the second line to the file, **you haven't committed anything**. Having said that

Ok... git tries to save your uncommitted changes, unless you force it to lose them. It will even prevent you from doing stuff so that you don't lose your changes.

Between command 5 and 6, you *haven't* committed the change to the file, actually, it's not even on the index. Command 6 switches to b, and that revision is poiting to the same revision you are standing on so git ways "ok", moving to b. You still get to have your file un-staged.

On command 8, you switch *back* to master, and git says "of course" (you are not moving to another revision so you are fine).

Command 11, file is finally in stage... but then again not moving from the current revision so it's all fine.

Want to see how git keeps you from moving sometimes? Commit right now (on branch b) and then do this:

```
git branch c master
git checkout c
echo hello > a
git checkout b # and here git should keep you from moving.
```

Comment: yeah...I understand that I haven't committed anything after I add the second line, I just wanna know why I added file 'a' in master branch, and then checkout to branch b, and I can still commit on branch 'b'. Is this only happen when both branches contain file 'a'? I mean, otherwise I may commit something that should not exist on branch b

Comment: It doesn't matter that you added while being on branch master. When you asked git to switch to branch b, git will _try to_ bring over whatever you have on index and working tree to the point you are asking to move. If it can (like here, there's no real movement), git does... **as requested**.